# ASP.NET MVC3 Best way to customize converting input parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, timezone

I'm going to add support of different timezone in my ASP.NET MVC3 app.

The solution is to store date values in UTC time, and store user timezone offset.

So, I need 2 things:

1. Send date values to user in "user time" (it's clear, I pass date to wrapper that convert time to user time)
2. Retrieve date from user in "user time" and convert it to UTC.

Question is - what is the nice way to convert **all** input date values to UTC time. Or is there a generic way to add some converting rules to ASP.NET MVC ?

This is ideal schema what I want (controller receive already converted values)

[image]

Comment: how will you know the user's timezone?

Comment: It's not related to question. Assume that I know it. F.e. some static variable.

Comment: Ok, I can get timezone offset from javascirpt code (-new Date().getTimezoneOffset()) and post it to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way could be to create your own ModelBinder that do the work of mapping and preparing the data for your action method in the controller.

[This post from Hanselman's Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx) should give you an idea of what I mean. Obviously I'm assuming that you can get all the data you need inside the method

```
BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext);
```

Like getting the user timezone with a repository or a hidden field in the post.